# How to process a Database Delta sql file in Azure Data Factory to update a MySQL database

Tags: azure-data-factory, delta

I have an .sql delta file that contains updates and deletions to a database tables. I have a database that contains the same tables that the delta is made for to update. Within Azure Data Factory what is the approach to achieve updating my database with this delta?

Delta is stored in Azure Blob Storage
I have a linked service with connection to my MySQL database.

The delta contains sql statements like Insert, Delete From etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To process `.sql` file in ADF you can use lookup to get the queries from file as below
set row and column delimiter as `;`.

[image]

Lookup Output:
[image]

Now to execute them in MySQL take foreach loop to pass each query to lookup under it.
[image]

In lookup attach MySQL liked service and query with expression `@concat(item().Prop_0,'; select 1 as demo;')`

[image]

Comment: this is great, it looks like its working for me - i am wondering is it possible to execute more commands at the same time or at least be able to reduce the amount of activity calls, as for each statements its calling the activities and it can be quite a lot of calls when theres a many many new rows to insert to the DB.

Comment: in addition to my follow up question: Would it be possible to batch the sql queries to be executed together? I see there is a script activity within ADF however it does not support MySQL as a linked service