# How to bulk process a Database Delta sql file in Azure Data Factory to update a MySQL database

Tags: azure-data-factory, delta

I have a database delta .sql file that contains updates to table in a MySql database. I understand that data factory can execute sql statements and I could parse the .sql file a csv split by delimiter of ';' to get the sql statements. However my delta file contains a large number of statements and looping this in ADF would mean it would call such activities potentially hundreds of thousands of times - is it possible to execute statements in bulk?

Reference to an implantation with iteration sql statements:
[How to process a Database Delta sql file in Azure Data Factory to update a MySQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78159313/how-to-process-a-database-delta-sql-file-in-azure-data-factory-to-update-a-mysql)

or if there not an efficient way to update through iterating the .sql file? Is the only sensible approach a function app to execute the sql?

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run all the queries in `.sql file` in a single batch itself. Below is the approach.

- Take the lookup activity and take the dataset which contains the `.sql file`. Give the different column delimiter and row delimiter which is not in the file itself. So that all queries will be included in a single row itself. In this demo, I gave `&` as delimiter.

[image]

[image]

- If you are using `azure SQL database for MySQL` then you can take script activity and give the below expression. If you use `mySQL database`, then you can use lookup activity to execute the SQL script. Give the below expression in the query text box of lookup activity/script activity.

```
@concat(activity('Lookup1').output.value[0].Prop_0,'select 1 as col1')
```

[image]

if the `select 1 as col1` is not concatenated with the output of lookup activity, then ADF will throw error. Because Lookup activity expects to return data.